# Angular - how to remove white background in modal form with round corners

Tags: css, angular

when opening a modal form with round corners I wish to remove the white background

[image]

This is my css for the modal form

```
.modal-msg {
  .modal-dialog {
    width: 25vw !important;
    max-width: 35vw !important;
  }

  .form-msg {
    box-shadow: -20px 20px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16); 
    background-image: linear-gradient(41deg, #40d2ea, #964ada 54%, #7d2abd 77%, #7c29bb 77%, #541b7e 91%);
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 120px;
    background-radius: 120px;
        
    .modal-header {
      border: none;
      padding-bottom: 0 !important;
      justify-content: space-around;

      .close-icon {
        background-image: url('close.svg');
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        margin-left: 10px;
        z-index: 100;

        &:focus {
          outline: none;
        }
      }

      .header {
        font-size: 33px;
        font-weight: 600;
      }
    }

    .modal-body {
      padding: 1rem 12%;
      
      .header {
        font-size: 33px;
        font-weight: 600;
        direction: rtl;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
      }

      .form-control {
        color: #112d60;
        font-weight: 600;
        &:focus {
          border-color: #112d60 !important;
        }
      }
    }

    .background {
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;

      .circle {
        position: absolute;
      }
   }
  }
}
```

I've tried setting the background to transparent and playing with background-clip I guess I'm using it wrong or in not in the right order
please advice,
cheers.

the html code using this is:

```
<div class="form-msg">
    <div class="background">
        <div class="circle left-circle"></div>
        <div class="circle right-circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="close()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-center header">
                <span class="inspire-text">Inspiration Msg</span>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @malbarmavi maybe you can help?

Comment: have you tried changing the `.modal-msg` or `.background` `border-radius` to the same as `.form-msg`?

Comment: That is not your CSS but CSS pre-processor. You need to recreate that image using the code output so that people can debug.

Comment: @BelleZaid yes it didn't solve the issue

Comment: @m4n0 not sure what you mean by 'its not your code'? its the relevant part from my entire css file?

Comment: can you share the `html` file too? You can remove the item in the modal and just share the structure for the main item in the modal. perhaps we can help more with that.

Comment: I mean that is not the CSS syntax but SASS.

Comment: @BelleZaid added the html code as you'll see it doesn't do much right now

Comment: is `.modal-msg` the main modal class for the modal? or is it `.modal-dialog`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out and overloaded `modal-content` like this

```
.modal-content{
    background-color: transparent;
    border:none !important;
}
```